# How to convert String to NSArray in swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

The below line is my `String`

```
"(\n {\n ID = 338;\n Name = "Driver ";\n },\n {\n ID = 339;\n Name = "Officer ";\n }\n)"
```

I need Below type of `NSArray` data

```
[
 {
    "ID": 338,
    "Name": "Driver"
 },
 {
    "ID": 339,
    "Name": "Officer"
 }
]
```

Following is the code I did so far

```
func fillupDataIntoArray(_ result: NSArray,IsFrom:String) {

    let resultArray : NSArray = result as NSArray;

     if IsFrom == "tbl_AttendanceLocation" {
     let dic = NSMutableArray()
     for i:Int in 0 ..< resultArray.count {
     let tempDict = resultArray[i] as! NSDictionary

        dic.add(tempDict as NSDictionary)
     }
        taskList_Array = []
        taskList_Array = dic.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
     }
}
```

Plz help me !

Comment: Why do you have a String which is the description of an Array? How did you get it?

Comment: That looks like an old style plist format, if that's the case you can use Apples plist parsing APIs, an NSArray and NSDictionary can be initialised with the correct format plist file, in this case NSArray.

Comment: @Larme i feel like that is a response from a request

Comment: @Larme: Yes, that is a response from FMDB data base. How it convert to as NSArray? Plz Help me!

Comment: You don’t. You manage correctly the array you had before turning it into a String. NEVER use description of an object to get it back. So please show some code.

Comment: Use _JSONSerialization_ to parse the string format and convert it into _Array_ format

Comment: func fillupDataIntoArray(_ result: NSArray,IsFrom:String) {
        
        let resultArray : NSArray = result as NSArray;
        
         if IsFrom == "tbl_AttendanceLocation" {
         let dic = NSMutableArray()
         for i:Int in 0 ..< resultArray.count {
         let tempDict = resultArray[i] as! NSDictionary 
           dic.add(tempDict as NSDictionary)   }
            taskList_Array = []
            taskList_Array = dic.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
         }
    }

Comment: @manoharaddanki Don't use `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift at all.

Comment: @vadian: How can i solve this issue, Plz guide me!

Comment: @manoharaddanki Larme already told you what to do. You don't parse string, you handle the response properly. There are literally hundreds of examples here.

Comment: "The below line is my String": It's unclear in your code where. Also, there is so much wrong things in your code: NSStuff in Swift 3+, all the `as`, the force cast, etc.

Comment: As Larme already told you, **you should not work on the String but on the original data**. Such a string is only for being human readable and debugging. What you need to parse is *the original data*, not the string you made from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    var ID: String
    var Name: String
}

let json = """
{
    "ID": "iuweguewbgw",
    "Name": "Sara",
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let product = try decoder.decode(GroceryProduct.self, from: json)
```

Also you can try Regular Expressions.